# Can someone explain this sentence?

Tags: sentence

> Historians see history as being driven by a combination of cumulative long-term trends and short to mid-term cycles, each of which contains the seeds of a subsequent but familiar situation.

Especially, I didn't understand the part "short to mid-term".

Comment: Note that you inadvertently omitted the words "combination of" from the first line of the block quote. I added them, to match the wording used in online versions of the quotation at three different sites.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence reads like something translated to English from another language. I say this because a native English speaker would be very likely to avoid using the word "mid-term" to mean "medium-length," since *midterm* has a very different standard meaning in English. *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for *midterm*:

> **midterm** *n* (1906) **1 a :** the middle of an academic term **b :** an examination at midterm **2 :** the approximate middle of a term of office

In short, the word *midterm* normally consists of *mid-* in the sense of "middle" plus *term* (in the sense of "academic or political block of time or tenure"); but the quoted excerpt seems to want to use it to mean *medium* (that is, "medium-size" or "medium-length") plus *term* (in the sense of "length of time"). But really, *medium-size* or *medium-length* would be a much better (and more accurate) word choice than *mid-term* for the author of the excerpt to have used.

Comment: This sentence is from Cambridge vocabulary for IELTS.

Comment: @Qələndər Mehdiyev: If _mid-term_ is generally understood in British English to mean "medium-term" (that is, "medium-length"), I must plead ignorance of the fact. In U.S. English, the meanings of the word _midterm_ are as the _Eleventh Collegiate_ specifies (and as I report them) in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This means, in context, that "Historians think that history is controlled by a trend that is seen only in long observations and that such trend acumulates itself, and [historians think that history is controlled] BY cycles that are short and that are medium, but not long.

Any question ask again.

Comment: Thannkss for your answer! It's clear now. You mean in this context "from" is omitted? From short to mid-term? :)

Comment: At the risk of putting words into Samuel's mouth (or keyboard): yes, "from" can be and is omitted in some contexts like this.  "The New York to Florida drive takes twelve hours." → "The drive from New York to Florida ...."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In this case, "short" and "med(ium)" are adjectives describing the noun cycles, and when there are adjectives, a when there is the word "to" between them, and the last of them is followed by the symbol "-", then there will never be the word "from" to help the adjectives describe the noun.

Comment: In situations like this, you should [edit] your first answer to clarify it, rather than adding a second answer.